# Apply calculation to result into inches

Tags: ios, objective-c

The result self.animal.legSpan below spits out a legspan value in cm

i.e.

25cm

I need help to apply a calculation to the code below (dividing the value by 2.54) after this to show inches afterwards

i.e. I would like the result to be

25cm - 10 inches

Thank you

```
- (NSString *)textForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath isTitle:(BOOL)isTitle {
    NSString *result;
    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            result = (isTitle)? @"Leg Span" : self.animal.legSpan;
            break;


        default:
            break;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: CGFloat convertedValue = self.animal.legSpan / 2.54; ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague but I believe you want this:

```
result = (isTitle) ? @"Leg Span" : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%fcm - %f\"", self.animal.legSpan, self.animal.legSpan / 2.54];
```

This will give you:

```
25cm - 9.84252"
```

If you want whole numbers then try:

```
result = (isTitle) ? @"Leg Span" : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%dcm - %d\"", (int)self.animal.legSpan, (int)round(self.animal.legSpan / 2.54)];
```

This will give you:

```
25cm - 10"
```

Comment: Thanks perfect, worked well with `double cm = [self.animal.legSpan doubleValue];
double in = cm / 2.54;
result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", in];`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`[NSString stringWithFormat:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSString/stringWithFormat%3a) to format your `float`/`double`/`int` (whatever it is) into a string object:

```
- (NSString *)textForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath isTitle:(BOOL)isTitle {
    NSString *result;
    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            result = (isTitle)? @"Leg Span" :
                                [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", self.animal.legSpan / 2.54];
            break;


        default:
            break;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that `self.animal.legSpan` is a NSString since you are using it as one.

Therefore, you need to convert it to a number, do the division, and then convert it back to a string:

```
double cm = [self.animal.legSpan doubleValue];
double in = cm / 2.54;
result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", in];
```

Comment: Thanks, very useful for code above!

Comment: Did you end up using this code, or the accepted answer?

Comment: I used both, how to I acknowledge both?

Comment: You can only accept the one that helped you the most.  Once you reach 10 points of reputation, you can up-vote ALL questions that you find helpful so that they get some points for helping.